# jsp- How to send value to database table to process?

Tags: ajax, jsp

I am new to AJAX and I have a JSP page that looks like below:

[image: Screenshot]

The new username column allows me to input any string of text and when I hit update user button,it should update the table in my database.

My table in database structure has a unique column `AUSERNAME` which stores the username as shown in the screenshot. After clicking the update button, it shall pass the new username value and update that field in table. This is what I am trying to achieve.

I know I have to make an AJAX call in my JSP page which looks like below:

```
<script >
    function update(param) {


        var currentbal = document.getElementsByName('NewUserName' + param)[0].value;


        console.log(currentbal);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update.jsp",
            data: { name: currentbal},
            success:function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Updated: " + msg );
            },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });

    }




</script>
```

As for my `update.jsp` page, I am not too sure how to work on it and make the changes to the table. I believe I need to create a function in it but unsure how to pass the values to it and use sql statements to update it.

Comment: post your jsp code also

Comment: my jsp code is empty at the moment

Answer (score 1):

In your jsp page you can do something like this :

```
<%@page import= "java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import= "java.io.*" %>

<% 
    //getting data send from ajax request 

   String id= request.getParameter("id");
String user = request.getParameter("name"); //name for example
  //data base code
   try{
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Connection con = null;
                ResultSet resultSet = null;
                Statement stmt = null;
               int row=0;
 try {
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc","root","swati");
String sql = "UPDATE `tablename` SET `user`=? WHERE `id`=?";      //updating table
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1,  name); 
            statement.setString(2,  id); 
                        row = statement.executeUpdate(); 
            if (row > 0) {
               String txt="updated";
            // forwards to the message page
           }
          }
          else {
            String txt="not updated";
             }
          }
         catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        } 

        }
      response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(txt);

        %>
```

Hope this help you !

Comment: You there, I have a question

Comment: Yes,Did you try it ?

Comment: Yes but I need a way to retrieve the id as it is written in java `rs.getString`

Comment: check out my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54395007/ajax-how-to-get-the-value-of-my-username