# ajax- How to get the value of my username?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have a JSP page that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The new username column allows me to input any string of text and when I hit update user button,it should update the table in my database.

My table in database structure has a unique column AUSERNAME which stores the username as shown in the screenshot. After clicking the update button, it shall pass the new username value and update that field in table. This is what I am trying to achieve.

I know I have to make an AJAX call in my JSP page which looks like below:

```
 <script >
    function update(param,param1) {


        var newuser = document.getElementsByName('NewUserName' + param)[0].value;
        var currentuser = document.getElementsByName(param1).value;



        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update.jsp",
            data: { name: newuser,
                current: currentuser

            },
            success:function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Updated: " + msg );
            },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });

    }




</script>

<form method="get" action="migratefolder.jsp">

    <%



        try {



            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gmc";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "root";
            Connection conn = null;

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");

            String query = "select ausername, ausertype from auser where AUSTATE='Y'";
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            String str = "<table border=2><tr><th>Username</th><th>New Username</th><th>User Type</th><th>Update</th></tr>";
              int rowid = 0;
  String currentuser=null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                rowid ++;

            currentuser=rs.getString("ausername");
                String autype = rs.getString("ausertype");
                str += "<tr><td><input readonly type=\"value\" name=\""+currentuser+"\" value="+rs.getString("ausername")+" </td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"NewUserName"+rowid+"\""+
                        "value=\"\"></td> <td>";

                if (autype.equalsIgnoreCase("Superuser")) {
                    str += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\"  value=\"Superuser\" checked> Superuser ";
                }else{
                    str += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\" value=\"Superuser\" > Superuser ";
                }
                if(autype.equalsIgnoreCase("Basic")) {
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\" value=\"Basic\"  checked > Basic ";
                }else {
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\" value=\"Basic\"   > Basic ";
                }
                if(autype.equalsIgnoreCase("View")){
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\" value=\"View\"  checked> View ";
                }else {
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype"+rowid+"\" value=\"View\"  > View ";
                }
                str += "</td><td><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"update("+rowid+","+currentuser+")\">Update User</button></td> </tr>";


            }










            out.println(str);
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    %>
```

For my update.jsp page so far looks like below:

```
  <% response.setContentType("text/xml");%>

<%

    String userid=request.getParameter("current");
    String user=request.getParameter("name");
//database connection
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Connection con=null;
    ResultSet resultSet=null;
    Statement stmt=null;

    int row=0;

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gmc", "root", "root");
        String sql = "UPDATE `auser` SET `AUSERNAME`=? WHERE `AUSERNAME`=? ";
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, user);
        statement.setString(2, userid);
         statement.executeUpdate();

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();


    }

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");



%>
```

The issue is I can pass the value of new username to the database but I need to specify the constraint on the current username itself to update to. As shown in my code, the Username values are retrieved using result set. For example,in the first row, I need to tell the table to update the username to `test` where `the constraint itself is USER1.`

Is there any way I can get the Username value in my function update?

Comment: please , post your jsp page where you are displaying table .

Comment: See my edited post

Comment: @Swati When I hit my update button, my table in database remains unchanged. what did i do wrong?

Comment: Yes, table name is auser and the column=Ausername contains username. I need to update it to `new username` so i used WHERE AUSERNAME since it's unique

Comment: Pls help me, already stuck on this for few days

Comment: Try to print value of user and current  user in your jsp page ? what are there values?   i think there values are null that's why query is not working

Comment: Which value do you mean?

Comment: For `newuser` it gives me correct value,say for 1st row, it shows `test` but for `currentuser`, i am unable to get the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187406/discussion-between-daredevil-and-swati).

Comment: I found the issue, it was a tag problem.However it shows rs.getString in the form too?

Comment: Are you there? A quick question

Comment: String autype = rs.getString("ausertype");  <-- remove this line

Comment: Okay, now I just use the third form you send me? It needs to be in java?

Comment: After I clicked the update button, the table remains the same and there's no error. What go wrong?

Comment: Did you change table name? Coulmn name? And name of request.getParameter(“something”);

Answer (score 0):

There is minor change required in update function to pass value.

you need to pass value in javascript function like this way.

```
<button onclick=update('abc','bcd')></button>
```

Check below code.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
    function update(param, param1) {

        var newuser = document.getElementsByName('NewUserName' + param)[0].value;
        var currentuser = param1;

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "update.jsp",
            data : {
                name : newuser,
                current : currentuser

            },
            success : function(msg) {
                alert("Data Updated: " + msg);
                location.reload();
            },
            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });

    }
</script>

<form method="get" action="migratefolder.jsp">

    <%
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "root";
            Connection conn = null;

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");

            String query = "select ausername, ausertype from auser where AUSTATE='Y'";
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            String str = "<table border=2><tr><th>Username</th><th>New Username</th><th>User Type</th><th>Update</th></tr>";
            int rowid = 0;
            String currentuser = null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                rowid++;

                currentuser = rs.getString("ausername");
                String autype = rs.getString("ausertype");
                str += "<tr><td><input readonly type=\"value\" name=\"" + currentuser + "\" value="
                        + rs.getString("ausername") + " </td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"NewUserName" + rowid
                        + "\"" + "value=\"\"></td> <td>";

                if (autype.equalsIgnoreCase("Superuser")) {
                    str += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype" + rowid
                            + "\"  value=\"Superuser\" checked> Superuser ";
                } else {
                    str += "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype" + rowid + "\" value=\"Superuser\" > Superuser ";
                }
                if (autype.equalsIgnoreCase("Basic")) {
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype" + rowid
                            + "\" value=\"Basic\"  checked > Basic ";
                } else {
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype" + rowid + "\" value=\"Basic\"   > Basic ";
                }
                if (autype.equalsIgnoreCase("View")) {
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype" + rowid + "\" value=\"View\"  checked> View ";
                } else {
                    str += " <input type=\"radio\" name=\"usertype" + rowid + "\" value=\"View\"  > View ";
                }
                str += "</td><td><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"update(" + rowid + ",'"+currentuser+"')\">Update User</button></td> </tr>";

            }

            out.println(str);
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>
```